# Unable to open File with Umlauts (chcp 65001/1252) with JAR - JAVA

Tags: java, cmd, command-line, jar, diacritics

I have a File that contains Umlauts (erklärung1.txt) that I need to process using my JAR File.

I implemented my Code in IntelliJ, and when I run it from there, it can find and open the file without any problems.

The problem happens when I run it from the command line on Windows since I need to run it as a JAR File. I have used the `chcp 1252` command, it did not recognize the Umlauts properly. Then, I used the `chcp 65001` command, this one did recognize the Umlauts but unfortunately I am still unable to find the File, not sure why - since the console prints out the path correctly.

Here is my code:

```
String pathOne = "C:\\Users\\takibu\\Desktop\\Erklärungen\\erklärung1.txt";
File pathFile = new File(pathOne);
if(pathFile.exists()) {
    System.out.println("It exists!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Path does not exist: " + pathOne);
}
```

And here is the output with the `chcp 65001`:
[image]

I am wondering, and have been searching for a while now, unfortunately without any luck, is there a way to find&open a File containing Umlauts from JAR & the console? The part that confuses me - as You can see, the path is printed out correctly in the console with the `chcp 65001` - but still, it is not found, although it is there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

PS: With command `chcp 1252`, I get this output: `ErklÃ¤rungen\erklÃ¤rung1.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update; I solved it by running

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar jarfile
```

Key here was `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).